# How to assess the incremental additive information of a new predictor in a Cox model using R?

Tags: r, chi-squared-test, cox-model, model-comparison

I want to check whether the addition of the new predictor `x3` improves the predictive information of a Cox model significantly or not.

So far I have:

```
> m1 <- coxph(Surv(time, y) ~  x1+x2,    data=a)
> m2 <- coxph(Surv(time, y) ~  x1+x2+x3, data=a)
> anova(m1, m2)
Analysis of Deviance Table
 Cox model: response is  Surv(time, y)
 Model 1: ~ x1 + x2
 Model 2: ~ x1 + x2 + x3
   loglik  Chisq Df P(>|Chi|)  
1 -319.85                      
2 -317.17 5.3526  1   0.02069 *
```

What about c-statistics? How can I calculate and compare it? Somewhere I read "C-statistic results were compared by the nonparametric method described by DeLong". What about other methods? What are the pros and cons of each method? And how do I all this using R?

**UPDATE #1**

Even after reading the manual, I do not understand how to use `rcorrp.cens` in my example. The following code

```
m1 <- coxph(Surv(time, y) ~  x1+x2,    data=a)
m2 <- coxph(Surv(time, y) ~  x1+x2+x3, data=a)
rcorrp.cens(m1, m2, Surv(a$time, a$y))
```

does not work. Which I have not seriously thought after reading the manual. However, I have no idea what to do. And which method-value in `rcorrp.cens` would be the best for me?

1. Would you/or someone else please give me a straightforward example; as possible derived from my example code?
2. Do you know ad hoc a published medical paper which used this statistical method in its analysis?

**UPDATE #2**

I am sorry, but unfortunately, I do not get it.  I wrote a executable example.

```
> library(survival)
> library(Hmisc)
> data(colon)
> d <- colon
> surv <- y <- Surv(d$time, 1-(d$status))
> m1 <- coxph(surv ~ rx+sex, data=d)
> m2 <- coxph(surv ~ rx+sex+age, data=d)
> anova(m1, m2)
Analysis of Deviance Table
 Cox model: response is  surv
 Model 1: ~ rx + sex
 Model 2: ~ rx + sex + age
   loglik  Chisq Df P(>|Chi|)  
1 -5522.6                      
2 -5519.3 6.4838  1   0.01089 *
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
> rcorrp.cens(fitted(m1), fitted(m2), surv)
Error in rcorrp.cens(fitted(m1), fitted(m2), surv) : 
  y must have same length as x
> fitted(m1)
NULL
> fitted(m2)
NULL
```

The manual on fitted says "an object for which the extraction of model fitted values is meaningful". But what is that? Apparently `coxph` is not such a model.

**UPDATE #3**

```
Following I show a working example incorporating the help from Harrell:

> library(survival)
> library(Hmisc)
> data(colon)
> d <- colon
> surv <- y <- Surv(d$time, 1-(d$status))
> m1 <- coxph(surv ~ rx+sex, data=d)
> m2 <- coxph(surv ~ rx+sex+age, data=d)
> anova(m1, m2)
Analysis of Deviance Table
 Cox model: response is  surv
 Model 1: ~ rx + sex
 Model 2: ~ rx + sex + age
   loglik  Chisq Df P(>|Chi|)  
1 -5522.6                      
2 -5519.3 6.4838  1   0.01089 *
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
> (r <- rcorrp.cens(predict(m1), predict(m2), surv))
               Dxy               S.D. x1 more concordant x2 more concordant                  n 
      6.069800e-02       2.345218e-02       5.282221e-01       4.675241e-01       1.858000e+03 
           missing         uncensored     Relevant Pairs          Uncertain               C X1 
      0.000000e+00       9.380000e+02       9.379880e+05       2.510688e+06       4.733685e-01 
              C X2             Dxy X1             Dxy X2 
      4.614846e-01      -5.326294e-02      -7.703084e-02 
> 
> (conc.m1 <- round((1 - r[['x1 more concordant']])*100, digits=1)) # smaller model with 2 predictors
[1] 47.2
> (conc.m2 <- round((1 - r[['x2 more concordant']])*100, digits=1)) # larger model with 3 predictors
[1] 53.2
> 
> (p.value <- round(2*(1 - pnorm(r[['Dxy']] / r[['S.D.']])), digits=4))
[1] 0.0096
```

Comment: Thank you for editing your Q. If it is now adequately answer (w/ @FrankHarrell's update below), you may want to accept his answer by clicking the check mark below the vote total to its upper left.

Comment: You may have NAs in the data and `fitted` may not be holding their place.  Try `predict(m1)` etc., and if that doesn't work use `predict(m1, d)`.

Comment: See my expanded answer.  And I guess `fitted` isn't implemented for `coxph` or `cph`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The likelihood ratio $\chi^2$ test as you have done is the gold standard.  You can supplement that with less sensitive measures such as $c$-indexes.  Also see the paired concordance notion "is one model more concordant than another" using the R `Hmisc` package function `rcorrp.cens`.  This is much more powerful than comparing two $c$-indexes.

The first two arguments to `rcorrp.cens` should be linear predictors or individual variables, e.g. `rcorrp.cens(fitted(small.model), fitted(larger.model), ...)`.

For your example the 2-tailed $P$-value for the 'more concordance' test is

```
2*(1 - pnorm(6.0698e-2/2.3452e-2))
```

which is 0.0096 in agreement with the better method you've already run.  A complication in interpretation is that with the Cox model, higher predictions mean shorter survival time so the linear predictor is negatively correlated with survival time.  That doesn't matter in the 6.0698e-2 but it does in the individual concordance probability estimates.  So interpret the output this way: in all possible pairs of observations for which survival time ordering could be inferred, the small model is more concordant with the outcome 1 - 0.528 of the time and the larger model is more concordant 1 - 0.468 of the time, which is greater.

Comment: Thanks for your patient help. I updated my "UPDATE 3" with a working example. However, I have difficulty to understand the phrase "more concordant with the outcome". Maybe it's just a foreign language thing. Am I right that 1-0.528 can be expressed as percent? And how would I refer to this … as U-statistics of model concordance?

Comment: No need to convert proportions to percents.  "More concordant" means that in random pairs of observations when a prediction is concordant with outcome, either the other prediction is not concordant or the difference in its predicted values for the pair is less impressive than the difference in predictions for the first model.

Comment: You wrote, that comparing c-indexes is less sensitive. Nonetheless, how could I compare these? And is a c-index the same as "Concordance= 0.561  (se = 0.039 )" which I get with the summary-function of a coxph-object?

Comment: You started out using the proper $U$-statistic kernel with `rcorrp.cens` (using paired pairs) and now you want to switch to an unpowerful approach.  This is not recommended.  If you don't want to exploit the paired pairing feature of your data, stick to the likelihood ratio $\chi^2$ test.

Comment: I do not want to report the c statistics; however, I would like to be able to calculate it, since it is very common in medical literature. This way I would be able to convince my colleagues. Can you recommand a paper comparing different test for this application (assumptions, how to interpret, pros and cons of each test, and so on) or do you discuss these tests in your book?

Comment: See http://www.citeulike.org/user/harrelfe/article/13265590.  Pencina now recommends the likelihood ratio test for formal testing.

Answer (score 1):

```
rm(list=ls())
library(mvtnorm) 
library(Hmisc)

full_IDX = 2:3
redu_IDX = 2
temp_p=numeric(5000)
for (i in 1:length(temp_p)){
data.df=rbind(  cbind(0,rmvnorm(500,mean=c(0,0))),
                cbind(1,rmvnorm(500,mean=c(2,0))))

m1=glm(data.df[,1] ~ data.df[,full_IDX],family = "binomial")
m2=glm(data.df[,1] ~ data.df[,redu_IDX],family = "binomial")

temp=rcorrp.cens(fitted(m1), fitted(m2),data.df[,1])
temp_p[i]=2*(1-pnorm(abs(temp[1]/temp[2])))
}
mean(temp_p<0.05)
```

> mean(temp_p<0.05)

[1] 0.1032

here i am simulating a second score (just noise)
it does not look like the type I error is controlled...