# Rank Correlation for Paired Predictor to compate 2 GLM models: appropiate objects and p-value

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, paired-data, model-comparison

Dear Professor Harrell and users,

Thank you for this post: [How to assess the incremental additive information of a new predictor in a Cox model using R?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/117332/how-to-assess-the-incremental-additive-information-of-a-new-predictor-in-a-cox-m/579549#579549), it has been really helpful for my work.

I am comparing two GLM models with the same amount of overfitting. Following your post I am doing:

library('Hmisc')

rcorrp.cens(predict(glm-model-score1), predict( glm-model-score2), phenotype, outx=FALSE, method=1))

[1] "score 1 versus score 2"

| Dxy | S.D. | x1 more concordant | x2 more concordant |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| -1.735882e-02 | 1.454669e-02 | 4.913206e-01 | 5.086794e-01 |
| **n** | **missing** | **uncensored** | **Relevant Pairs** |
| 1.267700e+04 | 0.000000e+00 | 1.267700e+04 | 3.948332e+07 |
| **Uncertain** | **C X1** | **C X2** | **Dxy X1** |
| 0.000000e+00 | 6.131310e-01 | 6.142637e-01 | 2.262619e-01 |
| **Dxy X2** |  |  |  |
| 2.285274e-01 |  |  |  |

These results seem to be appropriate, we're using predict() to get the linear predictor from the glm model and use it as the x1 and x2 objects. Is this appropiate?

From this post, we have considered using this formula to calculate a p-value to confirm or rule out similarity of predictions:

(p.value <- round(2*(1 - pnorm(r[['Dxy']] / r[['S.D.']])), digits=4))

However, we get values between 0 and 2 for the p-value, **P-value=1.7673** for the previous example. We wonder if the method we are using is adequate; and  if in our case it is a 1-tailed analysis and therefore we should not multiply by 2 to obtain the p-value.

Many thanks in advance for your time and help!